# Django call view methods with the same urls depending on the paramter

Tags: python, django, url, methods

I have following urls patterns.

```
   urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url('^api/create_workplace$', views.create_workplace, name='create_workplace'),
    url('^api/create_workplace/(?P<get_all>\w+)/$', views.get_workplaces, name='get_workplaces')
]
```

But when i'm adding get_all parameter always invokes `create_workplace` method.

Is it possible to call different methods with the same urls
depending on the parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a "/" in your urls config, try so:

```
url('^api/create_workplace/$', views.create_workplace, name='create_workplace'),
```

hope this works

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't change anything

Comment: does your get_workplaces view work when it is alone in the urls.py?

Answer (score 0):

Change patterns order. [Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem, I forgot to add second parameter to method

```
def get_workplaces(request, get_all):
```